# AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This is my code:

```
from example1 import db, Puppy

db.create_all()

sam = Puppy('Sammy', 3)
frank = Puppy ('Frankie',2)

print (sam.id)
print (frank.id)

db.session.add_all([sam,frank])

db.session.commit()

print(sam.id)
print(frank.id)
```

And this is my error:

```
& C:/Python/Python38/python.exe r:/dinabelajar/Flask-Bootcamp-master/05-Databases/coba/setdatabase.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "r:/dinabelajar/Flask-Bootcamp-master/05-Databases/coba/setdatabase.py", line 1, in <module>
    from example1 import db, Puppy
  File "r:\dinabelajar\Flask-Bootcamp-master\05-Databases\coba\example1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    import sqlalchemy
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .sql import (
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .expression import (
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\expression.py", line 34, in <module>
    from .visitors import Visitable
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .. import util
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .compat import callable, cmp, reduce,  \
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 172, in <module>
    time_func = time.clock
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
PS R:\dinabelajar\Flask-Bootcamp-master> & C:/Python/Python38/python.exe r:/dinabelajar/Flask-Bootcamp-master/05-Databases/coba/setdatabase.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "r:/dinabelajar/Flask-Bootcamp-master/05-Databases/coba/setdatabase.py", line 1, in <module>
    from example1 import db, Puppy
  File "r:\dinabelajar\Flask-Bootcamp-master\05-Databases\coba\example1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    import sqlalchemy
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .sql import (
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .expression import (
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\expression.py", line 34, in <module>
    from .visitors import Visitable
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .. import util
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .compat import callable, cmp, reduce,  \
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 172, in <module>
    time_func = time.clock
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
PS R:\dinabelajar\Flask-Bootcamp-master> & C:/Python/Python38/python.exe r:/dinabelajar/Flask-Bootcamp-master/05-Databases/coba/setdatabase.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "r:/dinabelajar/Flask-Bootcamp-master/05-Databases/coba/setdatabase.py", line 1, in <module>
    from example1 import db, Puppy
  File "r:\dinabelajar\Flask-Bootcamp-master\05-Databases\coba\example1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    import sqlalchemy
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .sql import (
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .expression import (
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\expression.py", line 34, in <module>
    from .visitors import Visitable
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .. import util
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .compat import callable, cmp, reduce,  \
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 172, in <module>
    time_func = time.clock
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
PS R:\dinabelajar\Flask-Bootcamp-master> & C:/Python/Python38/python.exe r:/dinabelajar/Flask-Bootcamp-master/05-Databases/coba/setdatabase.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "r:/dinabelajar/Flask-Bootcamp-master/05-Databases/coba/setdatabase.py", line 1, in <module>
    from example1 import db, Puppy
  File "r:\dinabelajar\Flask-Bootcamp-master\05-Databases\coba\example1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    import sqlalchemy
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .sql import (
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .expression import (
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\expression.py", line 34, in <module>
    from .visitors import Visitable
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .. import util
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .compat import callable, cmp, reduce,  \
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 172, in <module>
    time_func = time.clock
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Try updating your SQLAlchemy. `time.clock()` has been removed in Python 3.8.

Answer (score 1):

you must update SQLAlchemy

```
pip uninstall SQLAlchemy
pip install SQLAlchemy==1.3.6
```

Comment: Why the uninstall and not `pip install SQLAlchemy --upgrade`? How will this fix the error in the question, and why does it solve the question?

Answer (score 0):

change time.clock() to time.perf_counter() in python 3.8

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).